"A backslash escapes the following character" meaning

Any character that appears in a pattern, other than the special pattern character described below, matches itself. The NUL character may not occur in a pattern. A backslash escapes the following character; the escaping backslash is discarded when matching. The special pattern characters must be quoted if they are to be matched literally.

backslash escapes the following character—-> whats this means ? Can you give me an example?

I’m voting to close this question because This computing question is for Stack Overflow.

"What is the NUL character"  This is a technical computing question.  "NUL" isn't an English word, (it is the name of something in computing, and the same word would be used in French, German, Japanese or your language). SImilarly whether the  null terminor is matched by * is a computing question as is how the backslash works in regular expressions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775721/nul-character-linux-man-pages

The "null character" (a byte containing the value 0, with all bits off), normally signals the end of a string of characters, so it's not normally displayed anyway. It would be very difficult to include a null byte within a typical "character string" (a filename, for example), because any mechanism you use to assign a filename containing a null will almost certainly assume the string ends at the null byte.

You can do it in Unicode - U+2400 - the next is one character ␀

I think the question is, "What does, 'backslash escapes the following character' mean"? If so, this is the right place. That's a difficult sentence for a learner to parse, and this meaning of "escape" cannot be found in a standard dictionary.

This has been migrated to U&L once already, and briefly after that the user has asked the same question once again on U&L; the second question has been closed as a dupe of the migrated question, and the same dupe has been answered decently, explaining in english words exactly what it's meant by "ecaping" etc. I don't know if they're not reading the answers or what. But I doubt it'll stay open on SO.

@gotube Now I'm curious, do native speakers use "escape" with a similar connotation to the connotation typical of technical jargon in other contexts?

@kos No, it's only used in computing.

"Escape" in your example is computing jargon only. You won't find the definition in a normal dictionary. "Escape" is used with some types of strings, in this case, with pattern matching strings.
"Backslash" is the name of this character: \.
In pattern matching strings, there are certain special characters like * ? . + $ @ etc. that have special meaning, and cannot be matched normally. This means if you want to match a pattern that includes the + character, you need to use a special "escape character" before it to make it a normal character.
So the pattern A+$ matches any of these strings:

A
AA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

But it doesn't match this:

A+

Now, if you want to match the text "A+", you need to "escape" the '+' character so that it just represents the character itself, not any special meaning. That means putting the backslash \ character before it. So the pattern A\+ only matches:

A+

And nothing else.
Using the backslash \ character (the "escape character") like this on another character is called "escaping the character". I escaped the + character.
